# Using sicktoolbox on hydro

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to follow the sick laser tutorial, but I get this error "Couldn't find executable named sicklms" when i type rosrun sicktoolbox sicklms
I am using ros hydro on ubuntu 12.04
I am following the tutorial for the sicktoolbox_wrapper.

---

*I ran rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper sicklms , that's were the output comes from

Thank you, I am getting a timeout when trying to connecting to the Laser. This is the screen.

```
*** Attempting to initialize the Sick LMS...
    Attempting to open device @ /dev/ttyUSB0
SickLMS2xx::_setTerminalBaud: ioctl() failed while trying to set serial port info!
    NOTE: This is normal when connected via USB!
        Device opened!
    Attempting to start buffer monitor...
        Buffer monitor started!
    Attempting to set requested baud rate...
A Timeout Occurred! 2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred! 1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
    Failed to set requested baud rate...
    Attempting to detect LMS baud rate...
        Checking 19200bps...
SickLMS2xx::_setTerminalBaud: ioctl() failed while trying to set serial port info!
    NOTE: This is normal when connected via USB!
A Timeout Occurred! 2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred! 1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
        Checking 38400bps...
SickLMS2xx::_setTerminalBaud: ioctl() failed while trying to set serial port info!
    NOTE: This is normal when connected via USB!
A Timeout Occurred! 2 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred! 1 tries remaining
A Timeout Occurred - SickLIDAR::_sendMessageAndGetReply: Attempted max number of tries w/o success!
        Checking 500Kbps...
ERROR: I/O exception - SickLMS2xx::_setTerminalBaud: ioctl() failed!
ERROR: I/O exception - SickLMS2xx::_setTerminalBaud: ioctl() failed!
ERROR: I/O exception - SickLMS2xx::_setTerminalBaud: ioctl() failed!
[ERROR] [1383940385.005614654]: Initialize failed! are you using the correct device path?
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'SickToolbox::SickThreadException'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

---

I'm using a Plugable USB to RS-232 connector to connect the laser, I'll RS directly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99096/using-sicktoolbox-on-hydro/) by [iceburg6628](https://answers.ros.org/users/8586/iceburg6628/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-11-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) on 2013-11-08**:
Please edit the main question instead of posting more information in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for the help, it turn out my cable was bad.

---

Originally posted by [iceburg6628](https://answers.ros.org/users/8586/iceburg6628/) with karma: 16 on 2014-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0